# How to create a Sendlog functionality using in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, automationstudio, email-studio

Whenever an email is sent to target audience , client wants to know which email has been sent to customers and at what time its sent. Kindly provide a solution for it.

Comment: This sounds pretty much as standard reporting. Can you be more specific about the use case?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Create a Send log using AMPscript only

You will need to create a separate Data Exteniosn with all the fields that you would like to log and insert a script into all the emails that should be logged.
The function to use is [InsertDE](https://ampscript.guide/insertde/).

This is an example of the syntax:

```
InsertDE('DEname','FirstName', @FirstName, 'LastName', @LastName, 'CreatedDate',NOW())
```

It will update the FirstName and LastName columns with the first and last name variables.

---

Create an Email Send Logging Data Extension

Create a data extension in Email Studio to store email send log data.

```
1. Click Subscribers.
2.  Click Data Extensions.
3.  Click Create.
4.  Click Standard Data Extension.
5.  Select Create from Template in the Creation Method dropdown list.
6.  Select SendLog.
7.  Click OK.
8.  Enter the name, external key, and description for this data extension.
9.  Leave the checkbox next to Is Sendable unchecked.
10. Click Next.
11. Select the Use Data Retention feature if desired.
12. Create additional fields you would like to record in the send logging data extension.
13. Click Create.
```

Read the full instructions here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5

Comment: above u mentioned that is general process, i already did this one. i am asking about like same functionality how to create a sendlog in ampscript. for example: my client want to display his Particular emails only.

Comment: I have updated my answer describing how to achieve this using AMPscript.